# How to zip/unzip files in Powershell?

Tags: command-line-interface, powershell, compression

Is there a one-liner that will zip/unzip files (*.zip) in PowerShell?

Comment: related: [Unzip with PS in Server Core](http://serverfault.com/questions/446884/unzip-file-with-powershell-in-server-2012-core)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[DotNetZip](http://www.codeplex.com/DotNetZip) will allow you to do this from PowerShell. It is not a one-liner, but the library will allow you to write the PowerShell script you need.

You can also use the COM interface, see *[Compress Files with Windows PowerShell then package a Windows Vista Sidebar Gadget](http://blogs.msdn.com/daiken/archive/2007/02/12/compress-files-with-windows-powershell-then-package-a-windows-vista-sidebar-gadget.aspx)*.

Googling "zip powershell" or "unzip powershell" might also turn up useful results.

Comment: +1 Linked article has useful Tasks unlike the most upvoted answer

Comment: -1 for suggesting a Google search. This is the top StackExchange result in a Google search for "unzip powershell"

Answer (score 154):

This is how you can do it purely from Powershell without any external tools. This unzips a file called test.zip onto the current working directory:

```
$shell_app=new-object -com shell.application
$filename = "test.zip"
$zip_file = $shell_app.namespace((Get-Location).Path + "\$filename")
$destination = $shell_app.namespace((Get-Location).Path)
$destination.Copyhere($zip_file.items())
```

Comment: use $destination.Copyhere($zip_file.items(), 0x10) for overwriting existing files.  0x4 hides the dialog box, and 0x14 combines these and overwrites and hides the dialog.

Comment: Ok but how do you unzip?

Comment: The line `$destination.Copyhere($zip_file.items())` does the actual unziping.

Comment: You can parcel the above into a function, if you wanted:

`function unzip($filename) {
  if (!(test-path $filename)) { throw "$filename does not exist" }
  $shell = new-object -com shell.application
  $shell.namespace($pwd.path).copyhere($shell.namespace((join-path $pwd $filename)).items())
}`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Agree about accepted. Is not a monstruous code like other PowerShell i see. 5 Lines is just great and is fully related to Powershell not to 3rd party software.

Comment: This fails for me when the zip file contains just a folder (items is empty)

Comment: @Nico answer working for unzip in a destination

Comment: Does `Copyhere` support passwords?

Comment: Great! This works on PowerShell v2.0 and Windows 7

Comment: How to zip using your way ?

Comment: yes, how to zip with CopyHere?

Comment: how to zip with this method (> is command-prompt, src is a folder):
`>$shellapp=new-object -com shell.application
>$zippath="test.zip"
>$zipobj=$shellapp.namespace((Get-Location).Path + "\$zippath")
>$srcpath="src"
>$srcobj=$shellapp.namespace((Get-Location).Path + "\$srcpath")
>$zipobj.Copyhere($srcobj.items())`

Answer (score 56):

Now in .NET Framework 4.5, there is a *ZipFile* class that you can use like this:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.IO.Compression.FileSystem')
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($sourceFile, $targetFolder)
```

Comment: It *definitely* worked - I used it to extract over 400 zip files.  I'll check to make sure I don't have 4.5 on here, but it doesn't show up under Microsoft.NET.

Comment: This *would* be great if there were a simple method to ExtractToDirectory and an option to overwrite all existing files.

Comment: This works with .NET 4.5. You do however need Powershell V3 too.

Comment: [Article with example](http://vcsjones.com/2012/11/11/unzipping-files-with-powershell-in-server-core-the-new-way/) based on [related question](http://serverfault.com/questions/446884/unzip-file-with-powershell-in-server-2012-core)

Comment: Load the assembly with Add-Type, for example: Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

Comment: @JamesDunne - If you don't have other files you need to preserve, could use 'Remove-Item -Recurse $TargetFolder'.  Otherwise, what you want can be done, but it would be non-trivial.  You would need to open the zip for read, and then walk the zip, deleting any previous target object and unpacking the new one.  Lucky for me, the easy solution works.  ;)

Comment: Be warned that relative file locations will use the *.NET* current directory, *not* the PowerShell one. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11246068/1394393). It's probably better just to `(Resolve-Path $someDir).Path` the arguments.

Comment: Oh, I know this is 6 years old, but after trying to find a low-cost commercial (or open source) solution to extract files from a PKZIP SFX, and failing miserably, this solution right here made my day!

Answer (score 19):

I know this is a very old question, but I just saw it linked on Twitter on figured I'd post a current answer.

PowerShell 5, currently available on Windows 10 or via the [Windows Management Framework 5 Production Preview](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48729), comes with two built-in cmdlets for 'zipping' and 'unzipping':

- [Compress-Archive](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn841358.aspx)
- [Expand-Archive](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn841359.aspx)

Comment: It is a *good* thing to provide new information to old questions. ;) +1

Answer (score 18):

You may wish to check out [The PowerShell Community Extensions (PSCX)](http://www.codeplex.com/Pscx) which has cmdlets specifically for this.

Comment: +1 PSCX is a great set of add-on cmdlets - I just wish I could pick and choose more which ones I want and which I don't. It seems to be changing a whole lot in my Powershell instance....

Comment: I've come across this because I actually want to automate the PSCX installation if I can for some coworkers. Trying it now to see what sort of issues I run into

Answer (score 5):

I find the simplest solution to just use infozip binaries which I have used for years and use in a UNIX environment.

```
PS> zip -9r ../test.zip * 
PS> cd .. 
PS> unzip -t test.zip Archive:  test.zip
    testing: LinqRepository/          OK
    testing: LinqRepository/ApplicationService.cs   OK
    testing: LinqRepository/bin/      OK 
... 
No errors detected in compressed data of test.zip.
```

It would be straighforward to put a powershell wrapper around the text output but in practice I never need that so I haven't bothered.

http://www.info-zip.org/

Answer (score 5):

I also like [Info-ZIP](http://www.info-zip.org/) (the Zip engine found in most other Zip utilities) and [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), another favorite which has both a GUI and command line Zip utility. The point being, there are some good command-line utilities that will work for most PowerShell tasks.

There are some tricks to running command line utilities that were not built with PowerShell in mind:

- Running an executable that starts with a number in the name, preface it with an Ampersand (&).

  &7zip.exe
- Wrap each token, the utility is expecting to see from the command line, in quotes.

  &"c:\path with space\SomeCommand.exe" "/parameter2" "/parameter2" "parameter2's Value" "Value2 `" with a quote"

Try this:

```
zip filename.zip (Get-ChildItem somepath\*)
```

Or even:

```
zip filename.zip (Get-Content ListOfFiles.txt)
```

Answer (score 2):

James Holwell I like your answer but I expanded it a little bit

```
# Example
#unzip "myZip.zip" "C:\Users\me\Desktop" "c:\mylocation"
function unzip($fileName, $sourcePath, $destinationPath)
{
    $shell = new-object -com shell.application
    if (!(Test-Path "$sourcePath\$fileName"))
    {
        throw "$sourcePath\$fileName does not exist" 
    }
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $destinationPath -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
    $shell.namespace($destinationPath).copyhere($shell.namespace("$sourcePath\$fileName").items()) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[WinRAR](http://rarlab.com/) can work in CMD mode accepting arguments

Answer (score 0):

The ionic approach rocks:

https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PS-Examples

supports passwords, other crypto methods, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a PowerShell 2.0 compatible module that uses the native Windows OS commands to zip and unzip files in a synchronous manner.  This works on older OSs, like Windows XP, and does not require .Net 4.5 or any other external tools.  The functions will also block script execution until the files have all been zipped/unzipped. You can [find more information and the module on my blog here](http://blog.danskingdom.com/module-to-synchronously-zip-and-unzip-using-powershell-2-0/).