# Unzip File With Powershell in Server 2012 Core

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, windows-server-core

I need to unzip a file with powershell. The typical way I've seen everyone do this is by automating the shell with a script.

```
$shellApplication = new-object -com shell.application
$zipPackage = $shellApplication.NameSpace($zipfilename)
$destinationFolder = $shellApplication.NameSpace($destination)
$destinationFolder.CopyHere($zipPackage.Items())
```

This isn't going to work for me, as Server Core doesn't have a shell, so there isn't one to automate. This gives an E_FAIL COM error.

Powershell doesn't seem to be able to do it on its own, and if I go 3rd party, I have to figure out a way to script getting the utility on to the server in the first place. 7-Zip was my go-to, but it doesn't seem like I can script the download and install of it. Sourceforge keeps spitting me back HTML files.

How can I completely script unzipping a zip file in Server 2012 Core?

Comment: What's with the requirement to download 7zip from SF? Wy can't you install/copy from an internal source?

Comment: @longneck The PS script I am producing is going to be handed out to customers; so the script has to be entirely self contained. I *could* host a zip utility ourselves, but that is another headache I don't want (legalese). I was just hoping there was a simple Cmdlet that could do this that got intro-ed in 2012.

Comment: If you are handing something out to customers why not build a self-extracting archive?

Comment: @Zoredache Well, that seemed like more work initially (our build system is already building ZIPs), I was hoping it would just be "real quick".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Server 2012 comes with Dot.NET 4.5 which has [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile.aspx) which has a ExtractToDirectory method. You should be able to use this from PowerShell.

Here is an example.

First you need to load the assembly ZipFile is in:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.IO.Compression.FileSystem") | Out-Null
```

Then extract the contents

```
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($pathToZip, $targetDir)
```

Edit: If you have updated to PowerShell 5 (Windows Management Framework 5.0) you finally have native cmdlets:

```
Expand-Archive $pathToZip $targetDir
```

Comment: I just looked through System.IO.Compression  and ZipFile isn't there.  Is there an update to 4.5 that adds it?

Comment: It seems this was introduced in 4.5, but not present in 4.0. If you have 4.5 you should have it.

Comment: It's about damn time that there's a native solution for this.

Comment: [Blog post derived from this answer](http://vcsjones.com/2012/11/11/unzipping-files-with-powershell-in-server-core-the-new-way/)